# Restrict 0 at first digit in input textbox Angular8

Tags: javascript, html, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, angular9

How can i restrict first digit as 0 in the input textbox which accepts numbers.

for example:
Number cannot be like this 012345
Number can be like 123000

I have used pattern /^0|[^0-9.]/ but its not working in angular reactive forms.
My Input textbox control looks like below:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNumber" formControlName="inputNumber" maxlength="5" minlength ="1" pattern="/^0|[^0-9.]/"   [(ngModel)]="inputNumber"  required>
```

Any thoughts are highly appreciated.

Thanks for help.

Comment: why using `ngModel` when us using `formControlName`

Comment: I get value from database to show it dynamically in textbox. So i used ngmodel to display it. Incase i want to edit the text box my textbox should not allow first digit as zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use below pattern

```
[1-9][0-9]*
```

**Sample code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
Only numbers not starting with zero allowed.<br>
        <input type="text" pattern="^[1-9][0-9]*$" required oninput="if(!this.value.match('^[1-9][0-9]*$'))this.value='';"></input>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Textbox is allowing first digit as zero. So this solution does not match to my question sir. And it is not working as well in the run code snippet.

Comment: @user1989 I have updated the code above to check the pattern oninput. Try now.

Comment: @Liju What if I want to restrict number 0,1,2,3,4,5 ? I am using reactive form

Comment: Great thx alot , that's what exactly what my client wanted

Answer (score 2):

Use Reactive form & a custom validator with reactive form and check the value on change. This will give more control in handling the form. The below code shows two different error when the input starts with 0 or if it is not a number, It will also disable the form `submit` button any invalid input.

To populate the data in the input you can use `setValue` like done in `populateValue` function

```
import {
  Component,
  VERSION,
  OnInit
} from "@angular/core";
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  AbstractControl,
  ValidationErrors,
  ValidatorFn
} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      myInput: ["", [this.customValidator]] // custom validator
    });
    this.populateValue();
  }

  populateValue() {
    // use this to populate input with api response
    this.myForm.controls.myInput.setValue("wwedwedwed");
  }

  customValidator(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
    let error = {
      name: "",
      message: ""
    };
    if (control.value !== "") {
      // this validation will check if the value does not start with 0 or !isNaN
      if (isNaN(control.value)) {
        error.name = "notNumber";
        error.message = "Cannot be a string";
        return error;
      }
      if (control.value.startsWith(0)) {
        {
          error.name = "noZeroStart";
          error.message = "Cannot start with 0";
          return error;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
    return error;
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div>
    <input formControlName='myInput'>
    <div *ngIf="myForm.controls.myInput.errors">
      {{myForm.controls.myInput.errors.message}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type='submit' [disabled]="myForm.invalid">
 Submit</button>

</form>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-crhbgk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)